# Antminer s3 no ethernet setup

Tags: asic, mining-setup, antminer

So, Im the only tech savvy guy in my house unfortunately, and I live in the middle of nowhere, so my modem/ethernet data limit is limited to 10 gigs. My only way of feeding the internet to my computer is through my phones USB, cause thats all I can use to get unlimited data. Is there a possible way to set my antminer S3 to feed off of my computer while connected to my phone, and now to the modem?

Comment: Keep in mind that your miner needs a continuous connection to the Internet while mining.  So either you'll need to dedicate your phone to this task, or be willing to stop mining whenever you want to take your phone away.  On the other hand, pool-based mining doesn't necessarily need a large amount of bandwidth, so maybe your modem will be sufficient.

Comment: Also, an S3 will almost certainly cost much more in electricity than you will earn from mining, so you'll be wasting energy and throwing away money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your computer to bridge the connection from the interface that it is using to connect to your phone and the connection to the ethernet interface your Antminer is connected to. In this way, you share your phone's internet connection with your Antminer.

To do bridging, typically you open up whatever network interface settings are available for your OS. Then there is usually an option to create a bridge, and from there, you just follow the instructions.

Comment: So basically I would set my computer to work as the ethernet modem, correct? And everything in CGminer should work with that. And Im using a set of apps called pda net which is a windows to android bridge that feeds my phones data to the computer through usb debugging (sorry for not having that info in the post)

Comment: Basically you are just turning your computer into a network switch.